# Solving a state-space (2nd order equation) with ode45 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing, ode

I'm trying to teach myself how to use MATLAB for solving state-space systems, I have what seems to be a pretty straight-forward system but have been unable to find any decent straight-forward examples for a novice thus far.

I'd like a simple walk-through of how to translate the system into MATLAB, what variables to set, and how to solve for about 50(?) seconds (from t=0 to 50 or any value really).

I'd like to use ode45 since it's a 4th order method using a Runge-Kutta variant.

Here's the 2nd-order equation:

```
θ''+0.03|θ'|θ'+4pi^2*sinθ=0
```

The state-space:

```
x_1'=x_2

x_2'=-4pi^2*sin(x_1)-0.03|x_2|x_2

x_1 = θ, x_2 = θ'

θ(0)=pi/9 rad, θ'(0)=0, h(step)=1
```

Comment: What about the examples from the help page? [link](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) What are you struggling with?

Comment: So for instance, [even in this example](http://www.idsc.ethz.ch/Courses/vehicle_dynamics_and_design/8_2_Mass_Spring_Damper_Tutorial__11-08-08_.pdf) I don't understand how to translate my state-space system into a system of equations that is intelligible by ode45. (Just starting to use MATLAB)

Comment: Walk through? [Here you go](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/06/10/from-symbolic-differential-equations-to-their-numeric-solution/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a derivative function function, which, given the current state of the system and the current time, returns the derivative of all of the state variables. Generally this function is of the form

```
function xDash=derivative(t,x)
```

and xDash is a vector with the derivative of each element, and `x` is a vector of the state variables. If your variables are called `x_1`, `x_2` etc. it's a good idea to put `x_1` in `x(1)`, etc. Then you need a formula for the derivative of each state variable in terms of the other state variables, for example you could have `xDash_1=x_1-x_2` and you would code this as `xDash(1)=x(1)-x(2)`. Hopefully that clears something up.

For your example, the derivative function will look like

```
function xDash=derivative(t,x)
    xDash=zeros(2,1);
    xDash(1)=x(2);
    xDash(2)=-4*pi^2*sin(x(1))-0.03*abs(x(2))*x(2);
end
```

and you would solve the system using

```
[T,X]=ode45(@derivative,0:50,[pi/9 0]);
```

This gives output at `t=0,1,2,...,50`.

Comment: Ok so in the above, you use x(1) in the sin function, but don't seem to have set x_1 or x(1)?

Comment: Since `x` is an input to the function, we know it's value. We use `[pi/9 0]` to set the initial values for `x(1)` and `x(2)` and then they are updated every time step.

Comment: Is your code runnable? I'm getting an error "The selected section cannot be evaluated because it contains an invalid statement". It's complaining about t being unused.

Comment: Depending on how new your version of Matlab is, you can replace `t` in the definition of `derivative` with a tilde, `~`. But the code does run fine on my computer.

Comment: I'm using R2012b on a Mac, not sure, but I might just turn everything into separate symbolic variables and then call those

Comment: You shouldn't need symbolic variables at all. I am using 2012b on a Mac as well! How are you running my code? I save the function as `derivative.m` and call `[T,X]=ode45(@derivative,0:50,[pi/9 0]);` from the command window.